# How do I divide these two dimensions? (Custom table calculation)

Tags: tableau-api

I have two dimensions: Aspect which is either forecast or actual and metric which shows profit or number of trades.

Only mark is Value which shows values for each metrics and each aspect.

I need to divide profit/trades to get how much profit was per trade both for actual and forecast.

This is what it looks like in tableau:

[image]

Data looks like this:

```
BalanceDate Aspect   Metric Value
01-01-2018  Actual   Profit 100
01-01-2018  Forecast Trades 150
01-01-2018  Actual   Profit 200
01-01-2018  Forecast Trades 300
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate table to display the profit per trade, you can achieve this by using table calculation. Here is a step-by-step guide.

1. Right click "SUM(Value)" in Marks
2. Select "Add Table Calculation"
3. Select "Percent From" in Calculation Type, "Pane (Down)" in Compute Using, and "Next" in Relative to
4. Right Click "Trades" in the table, select "Hide"
5. Right Click "Profit" in the table, select "Edit Alias", change the name of the row to "Profit/Trade"
6. Right Click any values in the table, select "Format", then click "Fields" dropdown and select "% of Sum(Value)"
7. In Default - Numbers, select the format you like

The output:
[image: Output chart]

Please note that the input table is not in the ideal layout. You want the Profit and Trade to be in different columns because their values have different meanings.

Comment: Now is it possible to make % diff from these two? Profit/Trade forecast and actual? For example January 2 would be -4% from forecast?